# как переделать функцию вывода JSON

Tags: php, api, rest, рекурсия

```
function getDirTree($path)
{
  $result = [];
  $files = scandir($path);

  foreach ($files as $file) {

    if(! in_array($file, ['.','..','.idea','~components','~Arhive', '_plug'])) {

      if(is_dir($path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file)) {
        $result[$file] = getDirTree($path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file);
      } else {
        // $result[] = $file;
      }
    }

  }
  return $result;
}

$data = getDirTree('__Offers');

echo json_encode($data);
```

эта функция выдает **объект** с параметрами

```
{
  "dir1":{...},
  "dir2":{...},
  "dir3":{...}
}
```

как ее переделать что бы получать **массив** с объектами ?

```
[
  {"dir1":{...}},
  {"dir2":{...}},
  {"dir3":{...}}
]
```

Comment: никаких "объектов" "эта функция" не выдаёт. getDirTree возвращает массив, json_encode вовзвращает вообще строку

Comment: @InDevX оптимизация и лаконичность

Comment: В каком месте тут лаконичность если ты добавляешь бессмысленную лишнюю вложенность к массиву?

Comment: а как его парсить в таком виде ?  еше мне нужно применять filter на js

Comment: парсить так же как всегда. js прекрсно умеет работать с "объектами"

Comment: лаконичность я имею в виду на серваке nodejs где я буду парсить этот JSON

Comment: ну вот и учи node.js, как там перебирают массивы

Comment: @Ипатьев так в том то и дело что это не массив )

Comment: в РНР это массив. если в ноде это объект, то учи как работать в ноде с объектами

Comment: @Ипатьев в моем случае это не удобно мне нужно использовать методы массива так что проще  апи переделать

Comment: return [$result];